# Show that the set {$v: v^{T}A v \le 1$} is bounded iff $A$ is a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

Show that the set {$v: v^{T}A v \le 1$} is bounded iff $A$ is a positive definite matrix.Where $v$ denotes a column vector.

I more or less get the if part but I have no clue how to approach the only if part.
How can we infer so surely that $A$ has to be positive definite?

Comment: is there a topology present? What's meant by bounded here?

Comment: I think the norm is bounded here

Answer (score 3):

For the only if part: suppose that $w\neq 0$ is such that $w^TAw\leq 0$, then $\alpha w\in\{v:v^TAv\leq 1\}$ where $\alpha>0$ can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Ok, so how do you define boundedness for a set of vectors?

Comment: @LegendKiller There is a real positive real number that is larger than the norm of all the vectors in the set.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $A$ is symmetric (or consider $(A+A^\top)/2$).

Consider the eigendecomposition of $A$:
\begin{align}
A = U^\top\Lambda U
\end{align}
where $U$ is orthogonal matrix (by spectral theorem). Then the set becomes
\begin{align}
\{v: v^\top A v \leq 1\} = \{v: v^\top U^\top\Lambda U v \leq 1\}=\{U^\top w: w^\top \Lambda w \leq 1\}.
\end{align}
Since the map $w \mapsto U^\top w$ preserves the distance,
\begin{align}
\{v: v^\top A v \leq 1\} \text{ is bounded}
\Leftrightarrow \{ w: w^\top \Lambda w \leq 1\} \text{ is bounded}.
\end{align}
Since $\Lambda$ is diagonal, it is easy to verify that
\begin{align}
\{ w: w^\top \Lambda w \leq 1\} \text{ is bounded} \Leftrightarrow \text{diagonal entries of } \Lambda \text{ are positive},
\end{align}
which concludes the proof ($\Leftarrow $ part is obvious and $\Rightarrow $ can be proved by considering contrapositive).